# Formatting columns in microsoft excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

I have a list (.txt document) of telephonenumbers with first and surname and number.

Like this :

```
123123 john doe
123132 michael jordan
```

etc.

I want to put the list in microsoft excel that after a blank space means a new column

That I have a list like this :

```
number | firstname | surname
_______|___________|________
123123 | john      | doe
_______|___________|________
123132 | michael   | jordan
```

When I now paste my document into excel, `number`, `firstname` and `surname` are pasted into one column. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Doing it directly.

   a) Open a blank excel and go to 'Data' > 'From Text'.

   b) Browse for the document in txt and pick 'Delimited', Next.

   c) Uncheck 'Tab' and check 'Space'.

   d) Click Finish.
2. Going from where you left:

   a) Select the whole column, go to 'Data' > 'Text to Columns' > 'Delimited', Next.

   b) Follow steps c) and d) from the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the data --> convert tool to convert space /and/or tab into new columns:
[image]
[image]

Or you can import the data directly from text Data --> Import from text and choose space character as delimiter.